# How do I upgrade the security updates for the open deals distribution?

Tags: distributions, upgrading

I have recently installed the Opendeals distribution and am trying to install the security updates required.  I have tried the suggested method of overwriting all files but those in the /site folder but this does not work.

I have read the drush guidance but am not clear on this, are there any other suggested ways of updating drupal core with a distribution?

Comment: what do you mean by 'this does not work'.  How does it not work?